# gdb: (no debugging symbols found)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gdb, g++

I have a file called test. Even after compiling it with -g, when I run it in gdb, it says no debugging symbols found. I have also tried using -ggdb but it too was off no use. Please help.

```
Output for : gdb test

This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/test...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that you are attempting to debug the wrong program.

Your program is called `test` and yet you are debugging `/usr/bin/test` (a system program that will almost certainly be shipped without symbols; even if it did contain symbols, they wouldn't relate to your source code).

`gdb` will search `$PATH` to find the executable.  From [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Files.html):

> exec-file [ filename ] Specify that the program to be run (but not the
>   symbol table) is found in filename. gdb searches the environment
>   variable PATH if necessary to locate your program. Omitting filename
>   means to discard information on the executable file.

Try using the command:

```
$ gdb ./test
```

Comment: It simply says no such file or directory found.
I was following one tutorial on web on gdb and that is where they asked to use gdb test if the program name was test.cpp

Comment: And does the file `./test` exist?

Comment: I believe ./test is a way to execute test.out. And I have compiled test.cpp with output in test.out

Comment: @p_c Well whatever file is the executable is the one you need to debug.  If it's output as `cats` and that will be `gdb cats`.

Comment: Oh thanks.! I was missing out on the .out extension that we put for the output file in general :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `a.out` and then try again. It worked for me as I was also getting the same error.

```
rm a.out
gcc -g your_code.c
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the executable is not stripped, you can see that with `file /usr/bin/test`

Comment: Executing file /usr/bin/test in gdb gives me the same output.
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/test...(no debugging symbols found)...done.

Comment: can you post the result of `file /usr/bin/test`?

Comment: `Reading symbols from /usr/bin/test...(no debugging symbols found)...done.`